# Is this a blunder in the design of CSS?

Tags: css

CSS height 100% gives an element height that is actually greater than 100% by the size of the margin. Or seen another way, height:100% sets not the height of the element, but the height of the element excluding the margin.

One result is e.g. the following nonsensical outcome. 100% of the BODY in 100% of the HTML is too tall to fit within 100% of the HTML, hence producing a scroll bar.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title></title>
<style>
html, body {
height:100%;
}

#wrapper {
height:100%;
overflow: hidden;
}

#content {
height:100%;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id='wrapper' style='background-color:lime'>

 <div id="header">
 <p>line 1</p>
 </div>

 <div id='content' style='background-color:pink'>
 <p>line 2</p>
 <p>line 3</p>

</div>
</div>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

gives

[image]

and scrolled down

[image]

Is this a blunder in the design of CSS? Or does it in some other case act sensibly?

Comment: why don't you use a custom class which wraps around the entire page content and it the background color? This may solve the problem

Comment: Margins help to space elements from one another, but should be independent of the element's intended size.  If you want internal spacing that accounts for the element size, you use _padding_, although that has slightly different rules (adjacent margins overlap, whereas adjacent padding is added together).  If you want full height, the usual trick is to set the body padding and margin to zero, and wrap your page in additional containers.

Comment: not a design expert but I have seen designs where the scrollbar always present is a desired outcome (to avoid side-movement on the menubar, for example) - so making the height higher than 100% is a way to accomplish this.

Comment: Study up on the "box model", and in particular the `box-sizing` CSS property.

Comment: @torazaburo I have done. The current box model definition https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#box-dimensions accords with the nonsensical behaviour reported. box-sizing fixes up various related problems, but not this one. It doesn't offer the option of size including margin.

Comment: Well, margin is by definition "outside" the element. That's why it's called "margin". If you really need to, you could try things like `height: calc(100% - 24px)`.

Comment: " If you really need to, you could try things like height: calc(100% - 24px)" The problem there is that the 24px isn't automatically computed from the margin.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not a design blunder in CSS.

It is inherent in the concept of the dimensions of block level elements (width and height), vs margins (spacing that separates block level elements from one another), vs padding (spacing that separates the internals of block level elements from the boundary of the block.)

As a side note, I imagine the origins of these notions were inherited from print publishing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to get 100% by 100% of the viewport then use

```
body {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}
```

Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length for explanation & browser compatibility.

Comment: Adding that the the example fails to remove the vertical scroll bar. And it adds a horizontal scroll bar